# I need to add multiple dynamic field values into mysql databse

Tags: php, html

I created the Multi step form,it has three steps with continue buttons finally there is a submit button, i can add single values into my database but the php code which was written for dynamic field is not working,Here you can see my form.Here i have given my php code

form url
http://bootsnipp.com/snippets/XaXnv

```
<?php
$mysql_host = 'localhost';
$user_name  = 'root';
$sqlpw      = '';
$database   = 'jobfor_u';
$con = mysqli_connect($mysql_host, $user_name, $sqlpw, $database) or die("error.mysql_error($con)");
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $edu_lvl_arr = $_POST['edu_level'];
    $edu_fld_arr = $_POST['field_stu'];
    $univer_arr  = $_POST['university'];
    $edu_frm_arr = $_POST['edu_from'];
    $edu_to_arr  = $_POST['edu_to'];
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($edu_lvl_arr); $i++) {
        $edu_levl = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $edu_lvl_arr[$i]);
        $ed_fld   = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $edu_fld_arr[$i]);
        $univr    = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $univer_arr[$i]);
        $ed_frm   = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $edu_frm_arr[$i]);
        $ed_to    = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $edu_to_arr[$i]);
        $sql2     = mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO candi_education(can_edu_level,can_field_stu,edu_tim_from,edu_tim_to)
            VALUES('$edu_levl','$ed_fld','$univr',$ed_frm,$ed_to)");
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Show the HTML of the form.

Comment: http://bootsnipp.com/snippets/XaXnv

Comment: Add `or die(mysqli_error($con)` to the end of the `mysqli_query()` line, to see if it's getting an error.

Answer (score 0):

```
VALUES('$edu_levl','$ed_fld','$univr',$ed_frm,$ed_to)
```

Add single colon for the variables on values.

```
VALUES('$edu_levl','$ed_fld','$univr','$ed_frm','$ed_to')
```

Comment: `$ed_frm` and `$ed_to` are numbers, they don't need to be quoted.

Comment: Colon is `:`. Do you mean quotes?